# Regenerate all sequences in db (oracle)

Tags: oracle, sequence

Good day. I have a very specific task: regenerate all sequences in database. There is a 400+ tables in it, so I can't do it by hands. 
Can somebody help me to do it? 
Thanks a lot..

Comment: What do you mean by "regenerate?" What is your goal? Are you trying to reset the sequences to some new starting value?

Comment: What do you mean "regenerate" the sequences?  Are you wanting to drop and recreate the sequences?  Reset them back to an original state?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I need to drop all existing sequences and create again. But I'm not sure, may be some tables haven't sequnces.

Comment: Tables don't have sequences.  Sequences are standalone objects.  One sequence might provide IDs for every table in a schema (although that would be sub-optimal).  Also, what do you want to set as the starting values for the re-created sequences?

Comment: And.  You cannot drop sequences if they have been used to generate sequences that exist as data in tables.  You will break constraints.

Comment: @jim mcnamara - You can absolutely drop a sequence, even if it was used to populate data.  There are no constraints from tables back to sequences.  I assume you are meaning to say that doing this is dangerous as it opens you up to inserting the same data that was already previously inserted and thus breaking the uniqueness (and possibly the unique constraint) of that column

Comment: That is true - you can drop a sequence and not affect table.  The OP wants to rebuild the sequences.  The implication is: make new sequences to use with the same tables.  That won't work unless you are sure the sequences don't overlap.  Then, that obviates dropping the sequences to start with. I was not clear

Comment: Hmm. Now I know a lot of new.
Now I can formulate what I need. (Sorry, I'm just never use Oracle before). 
I need to check what tables in DB currently have no sequence and, if haven't, create it. And then write script with output like (<TableName>LastID is 'xx' <TableName>_SEQ_NextVal is 'yy') to check how existing sequences works.

Answer (score 0):

Please note this is highly dangerous. You may very well make mistakes. Run the select first to check what you're about to do and create a table of the select so you can re-create the synonyms manually later if you need to.

**Using `all_synonyms` or `dba_synonyms` *instead of* `user_synonyms` may result in dropping system synonyms *do not do this* if you want your database to work afterwards**

I'd also recommend testing the code on 1 test synonym you create to ensure that it does **exactly** what you want.

Plus I don't really see the point of doing this at all? If the synonyms are there why do you need to re-generate them? Or is this being done on another server? If so add `@server_name` after `user_synonyms` and remove the `drop`.

```
begin

  for xx in ( select * from user_sequences ) loop

    execute immediate 'drop sequence ' || xx.sequence_name;
    execute immediate 'create sequence ' || xx.sequence_name
                      ||  ' start with ' || xx.min_value
                      ||  '  ends with ' || xx.max_value
                      || case when xx.cycle_flag = 'N' then ' nocycle ' 
                              else ' cycle ' end
                      || case when xx.cache_size = 0 then ' nocache ' 
                              else ' cache ' end || xx.cache_size
                      || case when xx.order_flag = 'N' then ' noorder ' 
                              else ' order ' end
                      ;

   end loop;

end;
```